# Dont understand indexed system of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I$ be an index set and $H$ a function with domain that includes $I$. For each $i \in I$, we have a set $H(i)$. Definition:

> $\prod_{i \in I} H(i) = \{f : $f is a function with domain $I$ and for each $i \in I$, $f(i) \in H(i) \}$.
>
> Remark: The elements of $\prod_{i \in I} H(i)$ are all the functions from $I$ into $\bigcup_{i\in I} H(i)$.

It does not make sense to me how it is possible that $f(i) \in H(i)$. I believe my not being able to understand this is related to the remark says that the codomain of $f$ is $\bigcup_{i\in I} H(i)$, but I don't understand how $H(i)$ is the same as the set $H(i)$ (although I know that every "thing" in set theory is a set, but these two sets are different).

For example, say $H(x) = x^2$. Then the image of $H$ is $\bigcup_{x\in \Bbb R} \{x : x$ is a non-negative real number$\} \neq \bigcup_{x\in \Bbb R} H(x)$. At best, the image is $\bigcup_{x\in \Bbb R} \{H(x)\} \neq \bigcup_{x\in \Bbb R} H(x)$.

So I don't get how it is possible that $f(i) \in H(i)$, since at best it can be that $f(i) = H(i)$ (since $H$ and $f$ are both functions).

Comment: How could it be possible that $H(i)$ is not the same thing as $H(i)$? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You think about functions naively, like functions from the real numbers to themselves. But here everything is a set. So $H(i)$ is a set.

More generally one can approach mathematics under the assumption that everything is a set (like how all data is eventually a binary string in your RAM), in which case there is no problem with $H(x) = x^2$.

Comment: So $H(i)$ is a set, and $f(i)$ is also a set. The definition says that $f(i) \in H(i)$, so $H(i)$ contains an element $f(i)$. But the domain of these two are the same, so how can $H(i)$ contain $f(i)$?

Comment: We have that $f(i)$ is some element of $H(i)$. Note that $f$ is not $f(i)$.

Comment: Ok, for example purposes I'm going to use $H(x) = x^2$ again. For $x = 3$, we have that $H(3) = 9$, and $9$ is a set. The definition says that $f(3)$ is some element of $9$. The set theoretical definition should still agree with the high school intuition of functions, so I don't understand how this is possible.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.